# Cannot connect to database on Localhost | SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I'm trying to connect to my database from a software of control access and attendance (named Crosschex from Anviz), which ask for the following data:

-IP address, user, password, name of database

I'm using Localhost as IP address

I'm unable to connect to it because it throws a message saying

> IP address, user or pwd wrong.

I already created an instance, which is running. If I connect to the instance through SSMS, it works fine. I created a user associated to the database I’m willing to connect.

From SQL configuration manager:

- SQL Server is running as virtual service
- SQL browser is running as local service
- SQL server agent is running as network service
- SQL network configuration has named pipes enabled. TCP/IP enabled , in IP addresses —>IPall I had set port 1433. I restarted all services after this.

The funny thing is I already did this in another VM with same config and it worked out, had to changed it because of collation I have chosen before was wrong for my application. Is this somehow related to my app being unable to connect? My collation is Modern-Spanish_CS_AS, and is the only thing I changed comparing to the old VM.

Parameters of my System:

- Virtual machine on Virtualbox
- Win10 Pro
- SQL 2012 Express
- SQL Server Management Studio
- Software Crosschex

---

Edit

I got these logs but I'm not sure what they mean

11/17/2020 21:36:03,spid52,Unknown,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2011.110.5058' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_enumerrorlogs'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

11/17/2020 21:36:03,spid52,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

11/17/2020 21:35:02,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'anviz'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Master'. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

11/17/2020 21:35:02,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 38.

11/17/2020 21:33:34,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'anviz'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Master'. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.11]

11/17/2020 21:33:34,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 38.

[sql user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWIrQ.png)

[crosschex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5iqm.png)

[sql network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMGlj.png)

Comment: Are you sure you used LocalHost the last time and not 127.0.0.1?  They ask for IP rather than servername which makes me wonder if they really want a IP address.

Comment: What did the error log on the SQL Server side say? Did it register any attempt to connect? This is the only way to confirm whether SQL saw the connection attempt, or if the error is definitely beforehand.

Comment: @RandyinMarin Hi, Randy. Yes I’m sure last time (old VM) I used Localhost, because I tried with 127.0.0.1, and after my troubleshooting it worked fine with Localhost, so I keep trying in the new vm with local host

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee I edited the post with some logs I found interesting but not sure what they mean

Answer (score 0):

Your edit with the error logs tells you the error:

11/17/2020 21:35:02,Logon,Unknown,**Login failed for user 'anviz'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Master'.** [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

Will you please triple-check that your user account in SQL, `anviz`, has been access to the Master database? That's what your software is attempting to connect to. If you have granted access to the database[s], and you're still getting this error, let us know -- that'd be something tricky!

Comment: Hi, CoffeeNeedCoffee. I checked again at Login Properties of anviz user, and it has access to master db and anviz db, which is the one I'm trying to connect to. I'm attaching pics

Comment: Can you try setting the database to anviz in the connection string or setting the default db to anviz for the login?

Comment: @Nanto this is going to be a dumb question time, but: have you restarted that server yet? I've had authentication errors resolve upon reboot after first installation/configuration. (I know. I know. But I *have* to ask)

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee Don’t worry :) yeah a million times and it was the same. I think I figured it out but I’m not sure about the reason. I was going crazy and make like 6 VMs, all with same result. The first one (working) and last one (working too) have in the instance the parameter of Server collation as ‘Modern_Spanish_CI_AS’. All the other ones not working have ‘Modern_Spanish_CS_AS’, so I’m not sure how is this related to the error I was getting.

Comment: @RandyinMarin I tried setting the default db to ‘anviz’ in login properties of the user ‘anviz’, but I was getting the same error. I think I solved it changing the server collation of the instance but I don’t know why changing this worked.

Comment: @Nanto I wouldn't think case sensitivity to be an issue during logon, but did it work once you change the collation and restart the service?

Comment: When you create a new server, do you start with a new master and create a new sql login of the same name?  I normally script out the hash when moving a sql login.  I have to wonder if the hash would depend on collation.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee not really changed it cause I don't how yet :( instead, I made another VM with Server collation as ‘Modern_Spanish_CI_AS’. All other configurations: db creation, user mapping and server roles of user remain the same.

Comment: @RandyinMarin I don't really get what you're asking. Whenever I made another try,it was from scratch, I started with a brandnew Win10, installed SQL and created the instance and sa user, install SSMS, install the attendance software, created db and so on.. all within the VM. I used completely independent VM so I didn't mess it up with old installations. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: @Nanto, yes, that answers.  There are tools like rev_login that can script out a login with its "password".  I think it's a hash, not a password.  I never tried using it between servers with different collations.  I don't know if the hash algorithm depends upon collation.  I do remember when passwords because case sensitive independent of the server collation.